# Alternative Promise API

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Currently the promise executor looks like this:

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

});
```

the API would have been much nicer, if it was like this

```
let p = new Promise(r => {

    //  r.resolve() / r.reject();

});
```

could the API be updated to support this?

I am a fan of Constructor.create() style factory functions instead of new Constructor, so this should work:

```
Promise.create = function (fn) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fn({
      resolve,
      reject
    })
  });
};

function foo() {
  return Promise.create(v => {
    v.resolve('dog');
  });
}

foo().then(v => console.log(v));
```

Comment: Well, you could create your own class that extend `Promise` and have its executor however you'd like.

Comment: ok, i'll bite.  why would that not only be nicer, but MUCH nicer?

Comment: Having that single argument instead of two or more - (1) allows for flexible APIs, where the arguments list does not grow arbitrarily - just add a function or property to r (2) you wouldn't have to remember order of arguments (3) you don't have to type as much, especially not those pesky second set of parentheses. :)

Comment: You're essentially arguing that all multi-argument functions should really take only one object argument with all the args as properties.  That is a valid design pattern, but most people consider it best only for some circumstances and a situation with only two arguments that are both always passed is not one of those situations.  If you like that syntax so much, then just design your own factory function that works the way you want and simply use it in your own code and then you won't break everyone else's code that uses the standard way.

Comment: @jfriend00 for application code, whatevs, but for heavily used APIs, definitely helps to have to something well-planned. IMO this was a major oversight on the part of the promise API developers. Now they are pretty much stuck with what they have, unless they want to use a third argument like so: function(resolve,reject,thirdArg), or god forbid attach some property to the resolve or reject functions. Kind of sorry.

Comment: It's also nice to have that short single variable name (r, p, x, q, whatever) - you don't need to distinguish between other arguments in the args list, so a one letter arg is just fine.

Comment: No different than thousands of other Javascript APIs.  It really just sounds like you want all APIs to accept an object instead of multiple arguments.

Comment: Sure basically yes, I think unless there are overwhelming reasons in the reverse, then just attach everything to an object and pass that. Maybe they had performance concerns, for creating the container object that holds the two functions. Oh well.

Comment: It would be so much better lol, Promise.create() does it for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can patch/overwrite just about anything in Javascript (though I wouldn't recommend altering built-ins):

```
const NativePromise = window.Promise;

class Promise extends NativePromise {
  constructor(callback) {
    return new NativePromise((resolve, reject) => callback({ resolve, reject }))
  }
}

let pr = new Promise(r => {
  r.resolve('much better');
});

pr.then(m => console.log(m))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

It would probably be better to name your class `PinkySwear`, `BloodOath`, or whatever and leave `Promise` in tact to not confuse any other developers that may touch your code.

Comment: indeed, I will try this just too mess around

Comment: Won't this break ALL existing code that uses the standard `new Promise()`?  Why would this not be done with a new class or factory function that has it's own new name and those who want the new way can use that without breaking existing code that uses the ES6 standard mechanism.  This seems wholly the wrong way to do things.  It would be like redefining `setTimeout()` to take different arguments.  Make a new function that takes different args and don't break the existing standard's based one.

Comment: @jfriend00 right, it would break anything using native promises and is definitely not the way to do things. It is exactly the same as redefining setTimeout. If you reread my answer - I warned OP of this and suggested they name it something other than Promise. Despite it not being advisable, it is _possible_, which is what they wanted to know.

Comment: `It would probably be better to name your class PinkySwear` that's [taken](https://github.com/timjansen/PinkySwear.js) :p

Comment: @JaromandaX LOL it is!